# The Position of tables in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How can we configure **hibernate annotations** in the Entity class so that columns are created in a specific order. 
Example : id is the first column, lastName second, address third, etc. Using a Mysql DB,Hibernate is creating my tables in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this ... apart from creating the tables by hand using SQL "create table" statements.

My understanding is that Hibernate's "create in alphabetical order" behaviour is standard across all database types.  This is better than the old behaviour ... which was "create in random order" depending on the hash codes of the column names.  (That was fixed, because made Hibernate's generated schemas unstable; i.e. potentially different each time.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not create the order using hibernate configurations.I think it is an identified issue in hibernate.Have a look [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2396344)